# Chinese? Seal Need help with translating and more information on this scroll (Characters identified: 鄧紹新印）

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

I have searched and searched but cannot find what this means.  Can anyone help with translating this seal, or pointing me in the right direction? Thank you!

[image]

---

Thank you for the help. One of the translations show Shao Xin Deng Yin.
Is Deng Saoxin another way to translate this name?

Answer (score 1):

It shows 鄧紹新印.

I guess it is someone's name.

[image]

Comment: 鄧紹新(的)印. = Deng Shaoxin's seal

Comment: The arrangement of the characters is unusual.

Comment: @joehua Maybe 紹新鄧印 ?

Comment: @River isn't 印 typically at the bottom left corner?

Comment: @joehua Well, just because I have a friend also named 紹新X, so I think it might be the case.